# data_precision and data_scale Missing from Oracle's all_tab_columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I need to know the `data_precision` and `data_scale` values for the fields in a view in Oracle 12c. I am not the owner of the view and I do not have access to the underlying tables.

When I query `all_tab_columns` for this view, all of the view's columns report `null` for `data_precision` and `data_scale`.

Yet, I can see in the view that many fields are numbers such as `number(12,6)` or whatever. For example:

[image]

Yet we can see that `all_tab_columns` describes this column as:

[image]

(If the picture's are not clear, we have a column with values like 0.0003, yet `all_tab_columns` is null for `data_precision` and `data_scale`.

Basically, `all_tab_columns` would lead me to believe that the field is a `number(22)`, which is wrong.

How can I find out the actual data-type of the columns in this view? Why are integer types indistinguishable from decimal types in `all_tab_columns`?

Note: I tried to reproduce this with a trivial example, but instead of reproducing the issue, I got the expected/desired behavior.

e.g., this works fine:

```
create table foo
(
    bar number(19,6)
)
;

create view baz
as
select bar from foo
;

select
*
from all_tab_columns
where table_name in ('FOO', 'BAZ')
;

OWNER,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,DATA_TYPE_MOD,DATA_TYPE_OWNER,DATA_LENGTH,DATA_PRECISION,DATA_SCALE
LD_PRICING,BAZ,BAR,NUMBER,,,22,19,6
LD_PRICING,FOO,BAR,NUMBER,,,22,19,6
```

Comment: Just because the numbers look like they were created with a precision does not mean that they actually were. You can still store 0.0000025 in a number(18). A quick google suggests that Tom Kate agrees that this is entirely normal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see `NUMBER(12,6)` anywhere in your output. That column is simply a `NUMBER` without precision specificed.

```
SQL> create table t1(c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (0.00025);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1;

        C1
----------
    .00025

SQL> select data_length, data_precision, data_scale from  all_tab_columns where table_name = 'T1' and column_name = 'C1';

DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
----------- -------------- ----------
         22

SQL>
```

Specifying `NUMBER` is not the same as `NUMBER(22,0)` or `NUMBER(22)`:

```
SQL> create table t2(c1 number(22, 0));

Table created.

SQL> select data_length, data_precision, data_scale from  all_tab_columns where table_name = 'T2' and column_name = 'C1';

DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
----------- -------------- ----------
         22             22          0

SQL> insert into t2 values (0.00025);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t2;

        C1
----------
         0

SQL>  create table t3(c1 number(22));

Table created.

SQL>  select data_length, data_precision, data_scale from  all_tab_columns where table_name = 'T3' and column_name = 'C1';

DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
----------- -------------- ----------
         22             22          0

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. I was misunderstanding Oracle’s number type.

Comment: Probably related: all_tab_columns in some instances contains a data_precision null, data_scale 0 (instead of null). Data type is number.

Comment: Actual DDL for precision null and scale 0 is INTEGER. INTEGER has despite docs on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_datatypes002.htm 15 digits, so it is a decimal (-+10e308)